# How i can set image for array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Testing game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>     
    <div class="page">

<div class="upper"></div>

<div class="middle"></div>

<div class="lower"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
var weapon = [
"M4A1-S Golden Coil",
"USP-S Kill Confirmed",
"Shadow Daggers"];var price =  "39.16",  "23.38","135.92"  ];
```

How i set image for  "M4A1-S Golden Coil" and display image in
div class="upper"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loads weapon, price and image on .upper:

Steps:

1. Add another array for the image URLs.
2. Wait for page to be loaded with `window.onload``
3. Change the innerHTML of upper and use the values on the arrays.

```js
/* Your code. */
var weapon = [
  "M4A1-S Golden Coil",
  "USP-S Kill Confirmed",
  "Shadow Daggers"
];

var price = ["39.16",  "23.38","135.92"];

/* New code */

// Define
var image = ["http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/d/d8/Csgo-m4a1s-golden-coil-workshop.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150918211415", "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/9/96/Csgo-usps-kill-confirmed-announcement.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150918131537", "http://thingiverse-production-new.s3.amazonaws.com/renders/fb/39/21/a6/35/Immagine2_preview_featured.jpg"];


window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('.upper').innerHTML = '<strong> ' + weapon[0] + '</strong><br /><img src="' + image[0] + '" /><br />' + price[0];
}
```

```css
img { border: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="upper"></div> 
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

Play around with it to achieve your desired results.
However, I feel some context was missing.

*PS: I feel objects or classes would work better here. Example:*

```
var weapons = [
  {
    weapon: 'M4A1-S Golden Coil',
    price: 39.16,
    image: 'http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/d/d8/Csgo-m4a1s-golden-coil-workshop.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150918211415'
  },
  {
    weapon: 'USP-S Kill Confirmed',
    price: 23.38,
    image: 'http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/9/96/Csgo-usps-kill-confirmed-announcement.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150918131537'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/6ekw0a71/

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="upper"></div>

  <div class="middle"></div>

  <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var weapon = [
  {
    caption: "M4A1-S Golden Coil",
    src: "https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou-6kejhz2v_Nfz5H_uOxh7-Gw_alIITCmGpa7cd4nuz-8oP5jGu5rhc1JjSceNfXJVMgaVmB_QO-wLi5h5HovZ_Kn3A27HR24HrcnRC3g0lJbOFthPKcHwjIUrsJQvfN77TKZw/360fx360f"
  },
  "USP-S Kill Confirmed",
  "Shadow Daggers"
];

var price =  ["39.16", "23.38", "135.92"];

var upper = document.querySelector('.upper')

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', weapon[0].src);

var img = upper.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at script.js:17

Comment: Compare what you have with https://jsfiddle.net/6ekw0a71/ (no errors).  You are basically trying to add `null` as an element.  Make sure what you are passing in to `appendChild` is actually an element.